# Discrete optimization algorithms

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, discrete-optimization

Let $\pmb{a}, \pmb{b} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be fixed known vectors, then I have formulated the following minimzation problem:

$$\mathcal{X}^* = \arg\min_{\substack{\pmb{x}\in \mathbb{R}^d : \\ \forall k\exists j, x_k=a_j}}\min_{y,z,\in\mathbb{R}}\|\pmb{x} - (y\pmb{b}+z\pmb{1})\|^2_2$$

That is, I optimize over all vectors $\pmb{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ that may be constructed by using components from $\pmb{a}$, while the inner optimization is over some scalars $y,z \in \mathbb{R}$. Are there efficient, even if approximate, numerical algorithms to solve a problem of this kind?

My best idea was to relax the discrete optimization to a continuous one, so that $x_k \in [\min_{i}a_i,\max_{j}a_j]$. The issue is that even if I find a solution to the problem defined in such a way, I am not sure how to formulate a good projection onto the discrete set of solutions. It seems like the error may be quite large from performing such a projection. Any details/publications on how to realize this method, or suggestions for other methods are welcome.

Comment: Please specify what is given and what the optimization variables are. A useful convention is to choose the first letters of the alphabet to denote that which is given, whereas the last letters of the alphabet denote that which is unknown. Breaking conventions is legal, but readability is sacrificed.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I tried to clarify this. The variable naming scheme was purely tailored to the field I am applying this at, so I get how this may have been confusing. I didn't know about the standard convention - good to know. I will probably stick to simulated annealing for now, since the relaxation method doesn't seem very sound.

Comment: In your problem $\mathbf a$ does not really need to be a vector in $\mathbb R^d$. You are simply defining a set of permitted values $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_d\}$, and are optimizing over $\mathbf x\in A^d\subset\mathbb R^d$. This is essentially a [non-regular rectilinear grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grid) of $d^d$ points. Not sure if it helps in solving the minimization problem.

Comment: Maybe you could enumerate all the grid points that are locally closest to the plane $\{y\mathbf b+z\mathbf 1:y,z\in\mathbb R\}$ using some generalization of a [rasterization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm), and then test all of them to find the global minimum.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, a set $A=\{a_1,...,a_d\}$ actually makes the intent clearer. I am also aware that the search space is $d^d$, hence why I am looking for an approximate algorithm. The geometric interpretation of this as a 2D plane in a $d$-D space is also great. The solutions would indeed be restricted to those closest to the plane which greatly diminishes the search space. Thank you very much for the meaningful insights.